# Separate names with single quote and commas in php

Tags: php, arrays, directory

I have a directory where it content are saved in my database both files and sub dir name, now i have tried to select all to sub directories name so i can use it in sql select query but my problem is the selected dir show like this `cssjspageimages`.
How can i separate each dir name with commas and quote and also not add comma in last name?
Example of how i want it to look like `'css','js','page','images'`

```
<?php
$dirs = array_filter(glob('*'), 'is_dir');

if(!empty($dirs)){
$listdirs = ''; 
foreach ($dirs as $fileinfo){
        $result = end(explode('/', $fileinfo)); 
        $listdirs  .= $result; 
echo $listdirs;     
  }
}
?>
```

Bonus question
after i have get the sub file and dir like this `'css','js','page','images'` i will also add the main root dir example `'root','css','js','page','images'`

Here is my code

```
<?php
$cb = basename(dirname(__FILE__)); //the current base name
$root = "'".$cb."',"
echo $root . $listdirs;
?>
```

Now what if the root dir is empty? it will still add comma at the end of root and i will get error in sql select.
How can i fix this also

Comment: What's interesting is you did the hard part but can't figure out the easy part

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this:

```
<?php

$dirs = array_filter(glob('*'), 'is_dir');

if (!empty($dirs)) {
  $listdirs = '';

  foreach ($dirs as $fileinfo) {
      $result = end(explode('/', $fileinfo)); 
      $listdirs .= '\'' . $result . '\','; /* Enclose the $result in quotes (') and append a comma (,) */
  }

  $listdirs = rtrim($listdirs, ','); /* Strip the trailling comma */
  echo $listdirs;     
}
```

EDIT (answering the question edit):

```
<?php

$cb = basename(dirname(__FILE__)); //the current base name
$root = "'".$cb."'" . ($listdirs ? "," . $listdirs : ""); /* Check if $listdirs contains anything... if so, append a comma (,) and $listdirs... otherwise append nothing. */
echo $root;
```

Comment: can i ask a bonus question concerning this please

Comment: @Alex preferably, you should ask a separate question. But if it is just a simple glitch regarding this one, you can update this question and I'll update this answer.

Comment: The use goes like this  here is my current dir root and is possible that the user doesn't have any sub file or dir in it and it will show sql error because i did ths `$cb = basename(dirname(__FILE__)); " ' ".$cb." '," . $listdirs;` so when only to dir root it still has a comma at end and it will trigger error

Comment: Is just a small attachment question stack will not be happy if i ask that small question i should have attach it all together

Comment: @Alex can you please update the question with more detail please? From the comment I'm not understanding what your problem is. The `$cb = basename(dirname(__FILE__));` seems a separate statement from `" ' ".$cb." '," . $listdirs;` and I'm not understanding it.

Comment: @Alex but anyway, what I think you're looking for is something like: `cb = basename(dirname(__FILE__)) . " '".$cb." '" . ($listdirs ? ("," . $listdirs) : "");`

Comment: i want to kiss you now

Comment: @Alex check my answer. Edited to reflect your question edit.

Answer (score 1):

If the tasks in the original question and the follow-up 'bonus' question can be merged, I would recommend keeping the data returned by glob() as an array instead of converting it to a string right away.

Also note that:

- you can add GLOB_ONLYDIR to glob() so you don't need to filter the result
  through is_dir().
- glob() already returns the path-free basename so I
  don't think you need to go through foreach and explode the result
  looking for the directory names.

If that all sounds workable, this seems to do what you want:

```
$listdirs = "";
$dirs = glob('*', GLOB_ONLYDIR );
$cb = basename(dirname(__FILE__));

if( $cb )
    array_unshift( $dirs, $cb );

if( count( $dirs ) )
    $listdirs = "'" . implode( $dirs, "','" ) . "'";
```

Comment: this method fix the error i get here `$result = end(explode('/', $fileinfo)); //Strict Standards: Only variables should be passed by reference//$result = explode('/', $fileinfo); //Notice: Array to string conversion ` thank for that

Answer (score 0):

As John Conde said, you were really close :)

```
$listdirs .= "'". $result ."',";
```

Don't forget to remove the last characters of this string ( last comma), after the loop,  :

```
$listdirs = substr($listdirs,0,-1);
```

I think your "echo $listdirs;" should also be outside the loop.